# Is a semi-colon valid Sass syntax in a mixin?

Tags: sass, phpstorm

In PhpStorm (Version 2017 3) this syntax within a .scss file;

```
$blue: #0070a3;
```

is flagged with 'unexpected term'. As far as I am aware this syntax is valid. I can ignore it of course but it bugs me slightly.

Removing the semi-colon makes PhpStorm happy and compiles correctly so....

semi-colon or none?

http://sass-lang.com/guide has them.

Comment: In fact, it seems to be the semi-colon it is objecting to, removing that takes away the problem and the file compiles correctly. So I suppose my question has changed slightly.

Comment: it is `scss` or `sass`? they have 2 different syntaxs

Comment: There are Sass and SCSS syntaxes -- one of them needs semicolons and another does not. Better provide a sample code + screenshot of how it looks in IDE (including the file name with extension/icon visible).

Comment: it's a valid Scss syntax, and PHPStorm doesn't complain when using it. Please provide full code snippet (and make sure that file extension is `.scss` and not `sass` - semicolons are not supported in SASS)

Comment: It seems it's me getting confused between SCSS and SASS. The sass-lang.com documentation, on closer inspection, says that it uses SCSS syntax throughout. Thanks for the help. and @lena this was the problem, that my mixin file had a `.sass` extension by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The answer,  thanks to the commenters above, is that Sass syntax requires no semicolons whereas Scss syntax requires them.

So the valid syntax for my example above is;
`$blue : #0070a3;` in Scss and `$blue : #0070a3` in Sass